# $find not working in firefox. ASP.NET Slideshow Extender

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a asp.net ajax slideshow extender that I have hijacked and turned into a jquery like slide show control. It works wonderfully in every browser except for firefox. I have isolated the problem down to the $find call not working. Also I had to put in a setTimeout into the page to get pageLoad to call in firefox. This is also not necessary in chrome or IE.

Here is the code.

```
setTimeout ( pageLoad(), 250 );

 function pageLoad(){       
    var slider1;     

    slider1 = $find('<%= slExtender.BehaviorID %>');           
    slider1.add_slideChanging(onSlideChanging);          
} 

 function onSlideChanging(sender, args)
 {         
    currentSlideIndex = args.get_slideIndex();   
    //Do what you want using this index        

    var arr = <%= serializer.Serialize(linkArray) %>;        

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if(i == currentSlideIndex)
      {
         var link = document.getElementById(arr[i]); 
         link.className += "hovered";
      }
      else
      {
         var link = document.getElementById(arr[i]); 
         link.className = "";
      }
    }

 } 

function SlideClicked(slID) {
    var ss = $find(slID);
    var arr = <%= serializer.Serialize(urlArray) %>; 

    window.location = arr[ss._currentIndex];
}
```

It seems that the $find is returning null in firefox. Also, does anyway know why I have to put a timeout on the page to get pageload to call?.

Also the $find in SlideClicked does work. slID is the slExtender.BehaviorID

**Update**

If I add

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  pageLoad();
});

 function pageLoad(){      
    var slider1;         
    slider1 = $find('<%= slExtender.BehaviorID %>');           
    slider1.add_slideChanging(onSlideChanging);          
} 

 function onSlideChanging(sender, args)
 {         
    currentSlideIndex = args.get_slideIndex();   
    //Do what you want using this index        

    var arr = <%= serializer.Serialize(linkArray) %>;        

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if(i == currentSlideIndex)
      {
         var link = document.getElementById(arr[i]); 
         link.className += "hovered";
      }
      else
      {
         var link = document.getElementById(arr[i]); 
         link.className = "";
      }
    }

 } 

function SlideClicked(slID) {
    var ss = $find(slID);
    var arr = <%= serializer.Serialize(urlArray) %>; 

    window.location = arr[ss._currentIndex];
}
```

To the page, everything works fine in firefox and no longer works in chrome or IE.
I already have 1.4.1 included on the masterpage.

Comment: Are you attaching this code to the window.onload event? That could be the firefox bug.

Comment: It's in a usercontrol, so no I am not attaching it as I don't have access to the form tag.

Comment: THE firefox bug? I didn't know there was a well known bug with this behavior.

Comment: I was referring to the bug the bug you mentioned in the code. If the DOM isn't ready yet, then there could be issues with accessing elements before they're ready. Chrome could act a little differently than Firefox in how and when resources are loaded. I do know that most modern browsers load everything in parallel, so maybe there's a race condition? It's safer anyway to wait until the dom is completely ready before doing stuff.

Comment: Well, I think you are right, because SlideClicked() works and the only difference is that it is called on click which is most certainly after the DOM is ready. Chrome, IE, and Safari all work as expected. Do you have any ideas for a work around?

Comment: I wrote an answer that explains the idea. Try the suggestion, and if it works, use it everywhere. Relying on a setTimeout to guess when the DOM is ready is bad form and error prone.

Comment: the setTimeout was only to try and get it to work in firefox. I didn't need it or use it for the other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window object has an event 'onload', but this only works as expected in some browsers. With this, you would attach a callback to this and then execute all of your code that relies on the DOM. This isn't the same across browsers (sometimes onload is fired before the DOM is ready for traversal, which leads to problems), so you have to be clever.

Fortunately you're using a framework that supports it.  jQuery has a convenience function `ready()`.  Here's a basic example of how to use it (use this same form everywhere, since most scripts need the DOM):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // execute your code here, like adding event listeners, doing find, etc
});
```

So, with your particular code, do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    pageLoad();
});
```

I would recommend using this model always. Never call code in the global scope, but execute it when the DOM is ready. Even if you don't use the DOM, you probably will eventually, so it makes sense.

Comment: Will this work from a user control? I tried something like this the night I posted this question and couldn't get it to work. I will try again tonight and let you know.

Comment: $(document).ready doesn't get called in firefox. It works in all others.

Comment: Ah got it! The <script src="Symba/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> wasn't in my masterpage. Also, I needed to change my method name from pageLoad to something else.

Answer (score 0):

$find('<%= slExtender.BehaviorID %>');

In the above line, if "slExtender" is a control then you need to add #.

Make it like : $find('#<%= slExtender.BehaviorID %>');

Try this.

And for pageload problem try

$(function() {
 var slider1;

```
slider1 = $find('#<%= slExtender.BehaviorID %>');           
slider1.add_slideChanging(onSlideChanging);
```

});

Comment: adding the # broke it in chrome and IE and didn't fix it in firefox.